# JDO / GAE inheritance + abstract superclass NPE

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo

I would like to model a simple thing but getting in trouble when reading from datastore. I found this question in different flavours but none of the answers helped in my case (using an interface instead of abstract is no option) I´ve one abstract class Media:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, 
        detachable="true")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
public abstract class Media implements Serializable{

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk",
            value="true")
        ...
    @Persistent
    User owner;
}
```

Movie is extending it.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, 
        detachable="true")
public class Movie extends Media implements Serializable{
...
}
```

One User has a List of Media.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, 
        detachable="true")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk",
            value="true")
    protected String id;
        @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Media> ownedMediaSet = new ArrayList<Media>();
}
```

The reading operation code is:

```
@Override
public List<UserDTO> readAllUser() throws IllegalArgumentException {

        ArrayList<UserDTO> result = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();
        PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

        Query q = pm.newQuery("select from " + User.class.getName());   
    List<User> res = null;
            try {
        res = (List<User>) q.execute();

        for (User u : res) {
            UserDTO uDTO = new UserDTO(u.getId(),null,                        u.getName(), u.getEmail());
                result.add(uDTO);
            }// for

        } catch
```

This causes NPE:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at

```
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreTable.addFieldMapping(DatastoreTable.java:531)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreTable.initializeNonPK(DatastoreTable.java:440)
```

I dont get it. Without Media being abstract everything works fine. Maybe someone knows about the problem and can give me a hint.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can not make a list of Media... because there is no instantiable class of media.
--> that means there is no "database table" media

Polymorph relationship doesen't work with GAE...
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Polymorphic_Relationships

```
 @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Media> ownedMediaSet = new ArrayList<Media>();
```

Make the Class Media not abstract then it works.

Or you make a List of movies...

```
 @Persistent(mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Movie> ownedMediaSet = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

but thats probably not what you want.

so the last option is what's in this artikle:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Polymorphic_Relationships

make a list of Keys:

```
@Persistent
private List<Key> ownedMediaSet = new ArrayList<Key>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need a possibility to reflect all kind of relations and inheritance e.g. abstract superclasses. A List of the concrete type is no option. I think i´ll try with List<Key> although it seems not to be very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Try v2.0 of Googles JDO plugin and see how that goes. Likely it does nothing different yet, but if that is the case you can easily raise an issue *with simple testcase* at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/list The fact is the v1 plugin did some things in illogical ways (see Sam's answer for some links that this illogical handling caused). You could also just set inheritance strategy to COMPLETE_TABLE since that is all that is really supported with BigTable (i.e each class has a "Kind" that holds all properties for that type).

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be some config work. I'll try it once I have the time.